# Something wrong with my connection C# - Microsoft Access 2010

Tags: c#, ms-access, combobox, connection, ms-access-2010

Ok, so, I created a connection between Visual Studio's C# (2012) and Access. That means, I've done it the manual way (with no code). However, this method can't help me do exactly what I want, so I've done the coding way as well.

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.ComponentModel;
using System.Data;
using System.Drawing;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;
using System.Threading.Tasks;
using System.Windows.Forms;
using System.Data.OleDb;
using System.Configuration;
using System.Xml.Serialization;

namespace WindowsFormsApplication1
{
public partial class horaireForm : Form
{
    DateTime semSess;
    int numSemaine;

    int jourSem;
    int periode;
    string theoOuLabo;

    string lesCours;
    string cours;

    string lesProfs;
    string unprof;

    string lesLocaux;
    string lesGroupes;
    string laComm;

    string conn = "Provider=Microsoft.ACE.OLEDB.12.0;Data Source=C:\\Users\\Stanley\\Desktop\\stuff\\Hiver 2013\\Horaires_EcranA2013.accdb";
```

(Sorry if it's long). Anyways, after this, I have this code here that gets info from a combobox (each case is the date of the weeks of a college semester). Since apparently I can't select the primary key if it's the values in the combobox, I've decided to use the dates as the values to select in the combobox and then use it to select the actual primary key in the database.

```
semSess = Convert.ToDateTime(comboSemSess.Text);
        OleDbConnection laConn = new OleDbConnection(conn);

        try
        {
            laConn.Open();

            laComm = "SELECT NumeroSemaine FROM SemainDelaSession WHERE DebutSemaine = " + semSess;

            OleDbCommand myAccessCommand = new OleDbCommand(laComm, laConn);

            OleDbDataReader reader = myAccessCommand.ExecuteReader();

            while (reader.Read())
            {
                numSemaine = Convert.ToInt32(reader["NumeroSemaine"]);
            }
        }

        catch
        {
            MessageBox.Show("Une erreur s'est produite en accédant à la base de données");
        }

        finally
        {
            laConn.Close();
        }
```

However, I still can't connect. It still gets the MessageBox. Does it have to do with the fact that I've done another connection before it, or the way I typed the connectionString, because I have no idea.

Comment: why don't you catch the exception and see what its saying? catch(Exception ex){MessageBox.Show(ex.ToString())} and you will have a clue of what is wrong.

Comment: Thanks for answering. I completely forgot you could do that. Anyways, I tried doing that... And it syntax error when I try to assign "semSess" to "DebutSemaine". Says something like "DebutSemaine = 2013-02-25 00:00:00".

Answer (score 0):

I can see a few issues... in the `While (reader.Read())` block, you're overwriting `numSemaine` each time so you'll only ever get the last result in the datareader.
Also the date in the SELECT statement should have quotes around it (treat it like a string in SQL) and really it should be parameterised rather than concantenated (hard to SQL Inject from a combo box but not impossible and it's good practise anyway).
Also, a path just needs one `\` between directories, not two.

Comment: Thanks for your response. However, every time I put the path with only one "\", Visual Studio marks it red.